# Como impedir cadastro de usuário com Login iniciados por numero ou símbolo

Tags: php

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para fazer o seguinte eu tenho no caso esse função que faz no caso a verificação do login a ser cadastrado do usuário.

Caso ela inicie com numero manda um aviso impedindo o cadastro. Caso não comesse por número ela libera o cadastro deste login.

Ai eis o meu problema preciso que esse função iniba o cadastro  dos logins iniciados por qualquer simbolo ou caractere que não seja uma letra do alfabeto como @!#$%¨".+§=*/8 entre outros  ou iniciadas por números. Abaixo a função que eu fiz.

```html
<?php if(is_numeric(substr($loginPost,0,1))){ ?>
         o Login não pode começar com numero
  <?} else { ?>
          Usuário Cadastrado
   <? } ?>
```

Comment: Verifica se é de a-z ou A-Z; Se não for, rejeita login.

Answer (score 8):

Pode realizar essa validação de várias formas uma delas é um expressão regular que combine logo no início um intervalo de caractatres(a-z). `i` significa que a combinação é feita não diferenciando maiusculas de minusculas. A função que faz pesquisa com regex é [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php  
$logins = array('Admin', '007_bond', 'adm', '@dmin');

$regex = '/^[A-Z]/i';

foreach($logins as $item){
    if(preg_match($regex, $item)){
        echo 'login: '. $item .' valido <br>';
    }else{
        echo 'login: '. $item .' invalido <br>';
    }

}
```

A outra forma é utilizar a função [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) no primeiro caracter da string que no exemplo é `$item[0]`.

```
<?php
$logins = array('Admin', '007_bond', 'adm', '@dmin');

foreach($logins as $item){
    if(ctype_alpha($item[0])){
        echo 'login: '. $item .' valido <br>';
    }else{
        echo 'login: '. $item .' invalido <br>';
    }

}
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/s5an-d3xa)

Comment: Valeu era isso mesmo que eu queria muito obrigada pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Esse código você pode jogar em uma função caso vá usar em diferentes lugares.

Comment: @RodrigoFP, se a resposta está de acordo, marque-a como resposta aceita.

Comment: Gostei do `ctype_alpha`. Nesse caso, acho mais inteligente que a expressão regular. +1

Answer (score 6):

Adaptei sua própria lógica:

```
<?php
   $ascii = ord( strtoupper( $loginPost ) );

   if( $ascii < 65 || $ascii > 90 ) {
      echo 'o Login precisa comecar com uma letra';
   else
      echo 'Usuario Cadastrado';
   }
?>
```

### Explicando:

esta função retorna a *string* convertida para maiúsculas:

```
strtoupper ( $loginPost );
```

E esta retorna o código ASCII do primeiro caractere da *string*:

```
$ascii = ord( $string );
```

Aí basta comparar se é menor que `ord( 'A' )` (65) ou maior que `ord( 'Z' )` (90):

```
if( $ascii < 65 || $ascii > 90 ) { ...
```

... e apresentar a mensagem desejada.

### Alternativa mais tradicional

O código de cima equivale a esse, mas eu quis começar apresentando umas funções menos comuns ;)

```
<?php
   $letra = strtoupper( $loginPost[0] );

   if( $letra < 'A' || $letra > 'Z' ) {
      echo 'o Login precisa comecar com uma letra';
   else
      echo 'Usuario Cadastrado';
   }
?>
```

Adendo:

`$loginPost[0]` e `substr( $loginPost, 0, 1)` são a mesma coisa neste caso. Apenas cuidado quando for usar para *strings* multibyte, pois aí não tem como fugir de algo como isso:

```
$letraMultiByte = mb_substr( $loginPost, 0, 1, 'utf-8' );
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo pela ajuda também estarei usando ambos os scripts muito obrigada pela ajuda.